# Using scanner to allow my program to read in each line from a text file?

Tags: java, file, input

I've got a text frequency analysis program, I'm trying to alter this program so that it'll read all the text in a text file you specify. Every time I input the file name it throws an error at me, any idea where I'm going wrong?

**Error Message**:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.txt (No
>   such file or directory) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:120) at
>   java.util.Scanner.(Scanner.java:636) at
>   Charnock_John_4_.main(Charnock_John_4_.java:11) –

**Code**:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class J_<countlettersfilereader> {

      public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
      // open the file
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is the name of the text file? ");
    String fileName = console.nextLine();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
```

//

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.txt (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
 at Charnock_John_4_.main(Charnock_John_4_.java:11)

Comment: Probably, it didn't find the file.

Comment: @JohnnyC where is your file resided ? is it in the same folder as your java code?

Comment: yeah in the src folder.. not sure why it's saying it cant find it @KickButtowski

Comment: @JohnnyC can you try the full path to see how it behaves?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73608/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-johnnyc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to deal with the FileNotFoundException**

> 1. **If the message of the exception claims that there is no such file or
>      directory, then you must verify that the specified is correct and
>      actually points to a file or directory that exists in your system.**
> 2. If the message of the exception claims that permission is denied then, you must first check if the permissions of the file are correct
>      and second, if the file is currently being used by another
>      application.
> 3. If the message of the exception claims that the specified file is a
>      directory, then you must either alter the name of the file or delete
>      the existing directory (if the directory is not being used by an
>      application).

**Important:**

> For those developers that use an IDE to implement their Java
>   applications, the relative path for every file must be specified
>   starting from the level where the src directory of the project
>   resides.

Note: Your issue is number option one.

What I do to resolve this issue?

1. I usually use **absolute path** which I do not recommend because it is just Micky Mouse job.
2. Use **relative path** because your program will be path independent.